# Feeding AMS1117-5V with 3.3V

Tags: arduino, 5v, ldo, 3.3v

I need that an Arduino NANO clone work with 3.3V.

Can an AMS1117-5V give 3.3V if supplied with only 3.3V?

edit: current consumption is 400mA max. the AMS1117 output current is 800mA.

Comment: What current do you need?

Comment: Have you checked what the datasheet says?  We would have to look at the datasheet in order to answer this question.  We also would prefer that you look yourself first, then modify your question and ask about anything that you don't understand.  And, yes: output current that you need is an important part of determining the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First issue: a 5V regulator is designed to output 5V, not 3.3V, nor any other voltage. Don't use an AMS1117-5V for any output voltage different than 5V.

Second issue: every linear regulator needs some headroom. A practical 3.3V regulator needs slightly higher input voltage. This is called the dropout voltage. Dropout voltage of the AMS1117 is around 1.1 V, so to get stable 3.3 you need to supply it with at least 4.4 V.